# Why do I get the Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (main)?

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I'm writing a program for `esp32-wroom-32` using `esp-idf-v3.0`.
I'm trying to add logs, which will be saved in fatfs.
After some logs I get:

```
21:54:21.306 -> Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (main) 
21:54:21.306 -> Register dump:
21:54:21.306 -> PC      : 0x40089827  PS      : 0x00060b36  A0      : 0x40082179  A1      : 0x3ffd3860  
21:54:21.340 -> A2      : 0x3ff40000  A3      : 0x00000033  A4      : 0x00000033  A5      : 0x00000000  
21:54:21.340 -> A6      : 0x00000024  A7      : 0xff000000  A8      : 0xe37fc000  A9      : 0x0000007e  
21:54:21.340 -> A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0xffffffff  A12     : 0x00000004  A13     : 0x00000001  
21:54:21.340 -> A14     : 0x00000005  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x00000004  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000001  
21:54:21.340 -> EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xfffffff6
```

Why does it happen to main?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### FreeRTOS task stack depth

This is quite likely caused by a stack overflow in your FreeRTOS task.

**Increase the stack depth**

The first thing I would do is *increase the depth of the stack* for your FreeRTOS task. E.g., if you created your task with a stack size of `configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE`, this might be as low as 768 bytes - which is not adequate for a lot of common requirements.

**How much to increase the stack depth by?**

It is not easy to answer this, but - in this case - it may be adequate to simply increase it until you no longer have stack overflows. If you are concerned about not needlessly wasting memory, FreeRTOS [includes a mechanism](https://freertos.org/uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark.html) to let you know how close a task has come to overflowing its stack.

### Buffers and canaries

A [canary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries) is just a marker at the end of a buffer - which is checked periodically. If it is changed from its default value, it means that the program has attempted to write beyond the end of the buffer - i.e. there has been a buffer *overflow*.

Detection of stack overflow using canaries is enabled in ESP IDF by changing two options in configuration (under `Component Config` -> `FreeRTOS` section):

- 'Check for stack overflow' -> 'using canary bytes'
- 'Set a debug watchpoint as a stack overflow check' -> enabled

[image]

If you disable the second option, you will instead get a Guru Meditation error - a `LoadProhibited` exception - in the case of a stack overflow.

### `xTaskCreate()` and stack depth

Bear in mind that the version of `xTaskCreate()` in the ESP IDF differs from that in the original FreeRTOS. In the original FreeRTOS, the stack depth is [specified in *words*](https://freertos.org/a00125.html). In the ESP IDF, it's [specified in *bytes*](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/system/freertos.html#_CPPv411xTaskCreate14TaskFunction_tPCKcK8uint32_tPCv11UBaseType_tPC12TaskHandle_t). A *very* important distinction!

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to change my tasks stack sizes and it works!